# How to prepend segments to OpenAPI paths?

Tags: nginx, swagger-ui, openapi, quarkus

I created a REST endpoint following this guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json

Locally I can successfully use swagger UI on `<host>/q/swagger-ui` which uses `<host>/q/openapi` as input. So far so good.

However, in production, I use Nginx to forward the requests to `<host>/foobar`. Thus, the final URLs change to `<host>/foobar/q/swagger-ui` and `<host>/foobar/q/openapi`.

`nginx.conf` snippet where the Quarkus Docker container is running on port 49321:

```
         location /foobar/ {
              proxy_pass  http://172.17.0.1:49321/;
         }
```

In the `application.properties` I already added the following line:

```
quarkus.swagger-ui.urls.direct=/foobar/q/openapi
```

By doing this, Swagger-UI finds the OpenAPI spec. But the OpenAPI spec contains the wrong URLs because it doesn't know about the `/foobar/` URL segment.

How the OpenAPI looks:

```yaml
---
paths:
  /some/url:
    get:
      tags:
      - blabla
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
```

**How it needs to look** (`/foobar/` prepended to path):

```yaml
---
paths:
  /foobar/some/url:
    get:
      tags:
      - blabla
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
```

I already checked available OpenAPI properties on https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#openapi but they seem to not solve my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by setting the following in the `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.http.root-path=/foobar
```

and configuring Nginx as follows (`nginx.conf`):

```
location /foobar {
        proxy_pass  http://172.17.0.1:49321/foobar;
}
```

Comment: (suggestion: accept your own answer to mark it as a valid answer for the question)